# Add up all values in NSMutableArray and multiply by value depending on Plain Segmented Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray

What i want to do is multiply the latest NSMutableArray array entry (entered using a UITextField) by 3 when Moderate intensity is selected using the Plain Segmented Control and 6 when vigorous is selected and then display the total value of all entries in the array after the multiplications have occurred.  E.g. If there User selects Moderate using the Plain Segmented Control and enters 120 in the UITextField, I need a value of 360 to be displayed and for that value to increment as more entries are made.

So far I'm storing the array values in a table like below which works fine.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SecondViewControllerSegue"]) {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController
        = [segue destinationViewController];
    //secondViewController.infoRequest = self.nameField.text;

    NSString* style = (styleSeg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? @"Moderate intensity for" : @"Vigourous intensity for";

    [activities addObject:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Your activity: %@", self.activityField.text]];
    secondViewController.activities = activities;

    [activities addObject:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@: %@ minutes", style, self.nameField.text]];
    secondViewController.activities = activities;

}
```

}

I just can't seem to multiply and output the values. I've been playing around with something like

```
if(styleseg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

   3x(what the user entered in duration)
}
if(styleseg.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){

       6x(what the user entered in duration)
}
```

And a loop attempting to add up the total values in the array which is just outputting 0.

```
int result = 0;
for(int i=0;i<[activities count];i++)
result += [[activities objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
NSLog(@"result = %d", result);
```

I'm just having trouble blending the two together to do what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**NEW EDIT**

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *nameView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *activityField;
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *styleSeg;
}

@property UIView *nameView;
@property UITextField *nameField;
@property UITextField *activityField;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *activities;

- (IBAction)submitButtonTapped:(id)sender;
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "MyActivity.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize nameView;
@synthesize nameField;
@synthesize activityField;
@synthesize activities;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    activities  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //activityName  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.nameField.text = @"";
    self.activityField.text = @"";
    styleSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)submitButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"The submit button was clicked.");
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SecondViewControllerSegue"]) {
        SecondViewController *secondViewController
            = [segue destinationViewController];
        secondViewController.infoRequest = self.nameField.text;

       /* This was my initial code as in the intial question

        NSString* style = (styleSeg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? @"Moderate intensity for" : @"Vigourous intensity for";

        [activities addObject:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Your activity: %@", self.activityField.text]];
        secondViewController.activities = activities;

        [activities addObject:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@: %@ minutes", style, self.nameField.text]];
        secondViewController.activities = activities;

         */

        // New code
        MyActivity *activity=[[MyActivity alloc]init];
        activity.description=self.activityField.text;
        activity.duration=[self.nameField.text intValue];
        activity.intensity=(styleSeg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? 3:6;
        [self.activities addObject:activity];
        secondViewController.activities = activities;


    }
}
@end
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
}

@property IBOutlet UITableView *activityTableView;
@property NSMutableArray* activities;
//@property NSMutableArray* activityName;

@property UIView *secondView;
@property UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel2;

@property id infoRequest;

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize secondView;
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize nameLabel2;
@synthesize activities;
@synthesize infoRequest;
@synthesize activityTableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.nameLabel.text = [self.infoRequest description];
    self.nameLabel2.text = [self.infoRequest description];
    // activities = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController* parent = (UINavigationController*)[self parentViewController];
    [parent popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section.
    return [activities count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellReuseIdentifier = @"CellReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];
    }

    NSString* s = [activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = s;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Does the count go back to 0 when the user changes the segmented control? Or does it multiply all previous values regardless?

Comment: Your second view controller doesn't have an `activities` property. Also I am not sure why you are adding to the array in `prepareForSegue`.  I would have though you would have one button to add an activity to an array and another to trigger the segue to the second view controller

Comment: Isn't @property NSMutableArray* activities; right? And yes I'm not sure haha? I have it so once the user enters values in the activityField and nameField and then presses submit the array will be added to the UITableView and take the user to the next view controller in one go

Comment: Your @property is right, but it is on your first view controller.  Your `prepareForSegue` is trying to set it on your second.  It sounds like you could do this with a single view - fields at the top of the screen to enter the data and a tableView below.  You would then have an IBAction method linked to an add button at the top which adds the data to the array.  Your first view controller would also be your table data source (driven by the activities array)

Comment: Yeah I need it over two views however since I have much more to add once passed this roadwork. Anyway you're able to show me how to do it with the code I currently have? It was passing the required data before to the tableview I just couldn't get it to do the next bit as in the initial question. Heads about to explode I've been going around in circles haha. Really appreciate your help thus far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array seems to hold arbitrary strings, not integers represented as strings (the `intValue` of "10" is 10, but the `intValue` of "Moderate intensity for: 10 minutes" is 0).  Also you are adding multiple elements for each instance of an activity - the activity description and the activity duration.

I would create another object class to encapsulate the activity -

MyActivity.h

```
@interface MyActivity : NSObject

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *description;
@property int duration;
@property int intensity;

@end
```

Create a UIButton and set it's touch up inside event to `doAddToArray`. This will add an entry to the array for each new activate. Allocate a new `MyActivity` and set the appropriate properties before adding it to the array -

In ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)doAddToArray:(id)sender {

    MyActivity *activity=[[MyActivity alloc]init];
    activity.description=self.activityField.text;
    activity.duration=[self.nameField.text intValue];
    activity.intensity=(styleSeg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? 3:6;
    [self.activities addObject:activity];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SecondViewControllerSegue"]) {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController
        = [segue destinationViewController];

    secondViewController.activities = activities;


}
```

Then in SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIView *secondView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
}

@property IBOutlet UITableView *activityTableView;

@property UIView *secondView;
@property UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *activities;        // This is used to provide content to the UITableView

@property id infoRequest;

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;

@end
```

For brevity I won't include the full SecondViewController.m, but you have a number of places where you use `activities` that should be `self.activities`

Then to total the array (wherever you need to)-

```
int total=0;
for (MyActivity *activity in self.activities)
{
    total+=activity.duration*activity.intensity;
}
```

Comment: So I've gone right through my code to understand it all and I'm getting a Thread 1 message when attempting to submit the user data after running the program at the line cell.textLabel.text = [self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell; in SeconViewController.m which I can't work out?

Comment: The log is saying "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: `[self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` doesn't return a string, it returns a `MyActivity`.  You need to use `MyActivity *activity=(MyActivity *)[self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and then you can build a string using the `activity.duration` and `activity.intensity` properties

Comment: Not sure even how to even handle MyActivity being undefined

Comment: Make sure you #import "MyActivity.h" at the top of your SecondViewController.m

Comment: Oh sorry it's fine now was asking for an ';' even though it was there.. not sure. Anyway so do I still need to access cell.textLabel.text?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code in Xcode. check for typos?

Comment: So I'm kinda lost with this last part:  MyActivity *activity=(MyActivity *)[self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = activity;
    activity.duration;
    activity.intensity;

Comment: You can't assign the activity directly to the cell label, because it isn't a string. You can use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"activity duration=%d",activity.duration"]. Sorry, it is late here and I am on the iPad now, so I can't give you more complex code to use the activity.intensity field but I am sure you get the idea.

Comment: not a worry it's late here too so shall have a play tomorrow and go from there. Thanks!

Comment: So not sure what I'm supposed to be returning to actually see some output? I have MyActivity *activity=(MyActivity *)[self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"activity duration=%d",activity.duration];
    return self.activities;

Comment: Where do you have this?  You can assign the `[NSString stringWithFormat...]` to a label's text and see it in a label

Comment: I'm trying to display it using the UITableViewCell method so that the output is displayed in a table

Comment: Ok.  Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to retrieve the appropriate MyActivity from the `self.activities` array and then you can assign the formatted string to `cell.textLabel.text`

Comment: so in my cellForRowAtIndexPath something like:  MyActivity *activity=(MyActivity *)[self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"activity duration=%d",activity.duration];
    cell.textLabel.text = *activity;
 return cell;